# How to read a single file inside a folder inside a zip file with DotNetZip?

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

After some research, I found DotNetZip very easy to use when it comes to reading files in zip files. Sadly, I did run into a minor issue.

My zip file is set up like this:

- Top layer: zip file itself.
- Second layer: folder with the same name as the zip file.
- Third layer: data (including the file needed).

Using the following code, I keep stumbling upon it not finding an entry

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(modPath))
{
     string[] temp1 = modPath.Split('\\');
     string mod = temp1[temp1.Length - 1];

     mod = mod.Remove(mod.Length - 6);

     string modinfo = @mod + "/info.json";

     ZipEntry e = zip[modinfo]; // No entry found here
}
```

Am I overlooking something here?

Edit: Added the loop to get the name

[image: Inside a zip]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through the contents of the zip file using foreach and then find your file.

```
            using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(modPath))
            {
                ZipEntry e;
                foreach (ZipEntry k in zip)
                {
                    if (k.FileName.Contains("info.json"))
                    {
                        e = k;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: The problem with that is that I need to cycle through multiple zip files (same structure). I did make piece of code that would get the folder name completed, but it has the same result (no entry found)

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your folder.

Comment: Like... inside the zip you mean?

Comment: I did not fully understand the problem you are facing. Why are you unable to find the file by specifying the folderName. WHere are you trying to cycle through multiple zip files?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136654/discussion-between-m-schevers-and-codingdawg).